# Padding value in submit button

Tags: css

I would like to add a padding to the value of a submit button.

I am able to do for example `text-align: right;` and the value floats well right. But if i use for example `padding-left: 25px;` the value itself stays in the middle instead of moving 25px to the right. I found a lot of things about centering the Value but never to add a padding to it.

Example css code:

```
.sign {width: 262px;height: 102px;float: right;background: url("../images/sign.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;border: none;display: block;}
.sign:hover {background: url("../images/signhover.png");border: none;}
```

What to put in the above code to change the place of only my Value?

Comment: Can you add a http://jsfiddle.net demo?

Comment: add the HTML markup of your button's parent element

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n6C3p/)?

Comment: Here is an example in http://jsfiddle.net/W6pYW/ where the OK is in the middle, i want it slightly to the left. about 20px i also tried with text-align left or right but the float is to much for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
 padding-left:50px; text-align:left
```

From the example you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/ajy5q/

Comment: Nice Thanks that is what i want! Strange you have to set text align also... But nice!

Comment: You can see why in this picture: http://i.imgur.com/xWytcpd.png :)
Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding text-align: left;

```
.sign {width: 262px;height: 102px;float: right;background: url("../images/sign.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;border: none;display: block;padding: 0 0 0 25px;text-align: left;}
.sign:hover {background:  url("../images/signhover.png");border: none;}
```

I created an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZkR6/).

Comment: I appreciate the answer but i have already tried to use the align and the result is that it is to much to the right or left.